# Using logger in groovy class for soapui

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j, soapui

I have created the following groovy script in soapui (opensource).

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
class Test{

    static String hello(){
        def mylog = Logger.getLogger("")
        mylog.info("Hello")
        return mylog
    }
}

log.info Test.hello()
log.info loge here
```

It does not retrieve any error message and runs, but it does not retrieve the string in the info log (mylog.info) which is what I'm looking for.

Initially I thought 'log.info' would make it, which is the println equivalent when working with sopaui groovy script. But since I'm trying to write a log from a class, the class doesn't know 'log.info' by default, that's why I specified the use of 'log4j.Logger', but still not sure what I am missing.

Outside the class I put two log.info to print the value of both logger objects (the first one is the one from my groovy class and the second the one from soapui) and this is what I got:

```
Thu Feb 02 17:10:56 CST 2017:INFO:org.apache.log4j.Logger@24e6b930            
Thu Feb 02 17:10:56 CST 2017:INFO:org.apache.log4j.Logger@6ca396be
```

They look the same, except for what is after the @. Not sure what those numbers represents neither if that's part of the reason why my class does not write the info log.

If someone can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: do you want use `log` in you class?

Comment: yes, I want to be able to print different logs so I can trace what the class is doing.

Comment: log,context,testRunner are not generally available for classes. We have to pass it while instantiating the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks you are running into trivial issue.

Since `log` variable is already available in `Groovy Script` scope, you just need to pass that to your method as shown below:

**Groovy Script**

```groovy
class MyTest{
    static String testLogging(log){
        log.info("Hello")
    }
}
MyTest.testLogging(log)
```

[image]